# Sort aggregation buckets by shared field values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I would like to group documents based on a group field G. I use the „field aggregation“ strategy described in the Elastic documention to sort the buckets by the maximal score of the contained documents (called 'field collapse example in the Elastic doc), like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "body": "elections"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_sites": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "domain",
        "order": {
          "top_hit": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_tags_hits": {
          "top_hits": {}
        },
        "top_hit" : {
          "max": {
            "script": {
              "source": "_score"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query also includes the top hits in each bucket.
If the maximal score is not unique for the buckets, I would like to specify a second order column. From the application context I know that inside a bucket all documents share the same value for a field F. Therefore, this field should be employed as the second order column.

How can I realize this in Elastic? Is there a way to make a field from the top hits subaggregation useable in the enclosing aggregation?

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can. In this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) all the sorting strategy for terms aggregation are listed.

And they is an example of multi criteria buckets sorting :

> Multiple criteria can be used to order the buckets by providing an
>   array of order criteria such as the following:

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "countries" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "artist.country",
                "order" : [ { "rock>playback_stats.avg" : "desc" }, { "_count" : "desc" } ]
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "rock" : {
                    "filter" : { "term" : { "genre" : "rock" }},
                    "aggs" : {
                        "playback_stats" : { "stats" : { "field" : "play_count" }}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, my situation is a bit different. It is straight forward to define a sequence of order columns.
My problem: How can I access the (common) value of a field in all documents of the current bucket for sorting?
In your example above you group the songs according to the country of the artist. Let's assume you have an additional field artist.countryCode that stores an alternative representation of the country (meaning that the countryCode has the same value for all documents sharing a country value). I would like to sort by this countryCode.
How can I access this field?